# mod_rewrite and encoded parameters

Tags: javascript, apache, mod-rewrite, url-encoding

I am working on API running on PHP.
I want to send request in format

```
http://localhost/crm/api/addCustomer/John/Doe/Address 123/...
```

It worked, until I hit parameter address containing the / character. It shifted the data saved into the database, quite logically.

So I've done encodeURIComponent before submitting the data from Javacript

```
address = encodeURIComponent(getVal("address"));
```

Now I get 404 object not found when I try to call the API.

This is my current URL with encoded data

```
http://localhost/crm/api/addCustomer/John/Doe/Address%202166%2F62/.....
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /crm/api


RewriteRule ^getCustomers apihandler.php?action=getCustomers [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^getCustomer/(.*)$ apihandler.php?action=getCustomer&id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^addCustomer/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) apihandler.php?action=addCustomer&name=$1&surname=$2&address=$3&country=$4&email=$5&phone=$6 [NC,L,QSA]
```

How to fix this?

Comment: First of all, you should not be using `GET` request to create new record. `GET` is for getting things, not for creating them. Use `POST` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put `AllowEncodedSlashes Nodecode` into your virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ...
    DocumentRoot ...
    AllowEncodedSlashes Nodecode
    ...
```